# Word or phrase for sudden fast breathing not caused by physical exertion

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I am writing a story and I am at a loss for a word/phrase. The scene is as follows:

Two young people have fallen in love with each other. They are doing a slow dance and suddenly get too close to each other. They breathe in a fast manner. What is this type of breathing called? What is the word/phrase for this?

Comment: Shallow breathing.

Comment: What synonyms of 'breathe' did your thesaurus give you?

Comment: There is also "pant"...

Comment: @Cascabel — As in the famous “his breath came in short pants”. Ahmed, don’t give up the day job.

Comment: You can also use 'gasp' or 'gasp for breath', although this can sometimes mean it is difficult to breathe (which may be figuratively accurate in your scenario).

Comment: Sometimes, Ahmad, you just have to accept that there isn't a pre-existing word or phrase to describe what you want. That's the mark of a great writer, someone who can put into words those difficult emotions which are hard to describe.

Comment: His breath quickened, as did hers.

Answer (score 1):

In the extreme you could use "they started to hyperventilate." Can you provide some of the sentences you have so far so we can be more helpful in context?

Comment: Not a very romantic way to describe it ! :)

Comment: exactly my thought. no toot romantic

Answer (score -1):

[Pant](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/pant):

> to breathe quickly and loudly through your mouth, usually because you
>   have been doing something energetic

[Gasp](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/gasp):

> to breathe loudly and with difficulty, trying to get more air

[Hyperpnea](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/hyperpnoea):

> an increase in the breathing rate or in the depth of breathing, as
>   after strenuous exercise